# JQuery UI date picker working in jsbin but not locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i'm using sublime text 3 and i've tested other jQuery UI elements but decided to try using date picker today with a small project i'm putting together.  I notice that when I wanted to try it out I first saved the default code from the example on jQuery's site locally in it's own .html file, then I tried to load it up.

default code from example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Date:
            <input type="text" id="datepicker">
        </p>
    </body>

</html>
```

unfortunately, this brings up an input field but, on clicking into the field, i get no ability to select a date. In fact the date selection dropdown doesn't show up at all but I can tell that the input field has been selected.  I thought perhaps I had left something out when copying the code over to my test file so I loaded up JSBin and pasted the code there.  Magically, it works.   [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/fiqiwupewo/1/edit)I'm assuming i'm somehow not linking to the appropriate style sheet or the CDN for the jQuery UI.  Is that assumption correct or why isn't this working locally?

Comment: Do you have any error from console?

Comment: i forgot to check there but yes I do have a few errors. ><

[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (jquery-ui.css, line 0)

[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (jquery-1.10.2.js, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (jquery-ui.js, line 0)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
 (anonymous function) (date.html, line 11)
[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (style.css, line 0)

Comment: I've tested your code and it work, maybe you lost internet connection while loading the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

P.S- I have removed link to css file as it might have been your local css file. You can add that back.

Comment: hmmm...i tried adding http as well but that didn't seem to do it for me.

Comment: Can you try again with the code i posted. I ran the same on my local machine and its working

Comment: that must have been it.  it worked now. thanks.  Not sure why this didn't work when I tried it at first.  Also, can you explain why you got rid of the demos style sheet?

Comment: I thought it was your local file and since i don't have it, it would have thrown an error in my console, which I don't like :D You can add it back, it won't have any impact.

Comment: hmmm...that was actually in the example file from jquery's site.  perhaps that was what was throwing the errors.

Comment: thank you again.  will accept as the answer in 2 minutes